# How to get Data From Database To XML for Java

Tags: java, mysql, xml, sql-server-2008

I just have a simple question is it possible to get data from MySQL database to XML in a web page. For example i have a public form website in which a user can post and answer questions and i want to get data from database of my website and into an XML tree structure so i can use XML parser in my desktop app to get data from that website to my app.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: It is! (obligatory padding here)

Comment: @BrianAgnew What do you mean

Comment: He's looking how to convert data from MySQL select to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually convert your `ResultSet` into `XML` looping through it items.

Comment: Is there any good tutorial i tried but could not find any

Comment: http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3329001/Converting-JDBC-Result-Sets-to-XML.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes You Can do this by Using [Jaxb][1], It help to bring data from java object to xml. so for that you have to bring data in java object by using sql and then java object to xml.[1]: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html#jaxb